# Reaching the edge of overflow: hidden 'curtain' in TweenMax

Tags: javascript, scroll, overflow, gsap

I have a `div` with `overflow: hidden;`

Underneath this div, there is another `div` which needs to be `scrollable`.

Scrolling bit works fine with `TweenMax`, but I need to determine whether I have reached the edge of the parent `div` or not after every `scroll`, to change the `direction` of the `scroll`. And I cannot figure out how to do this part.

Here is a quick pen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGJVOm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, I think you can do something like below:

```js
var scrollButton = document.getElementById('scroll');
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
var inner = document.getElementsByClassName('inner')[0];
var containerWidth = 0;
var containerMaxWidth = 0;
var totalDuration = 1;
var duration = 0.8;
var ease = Power2.easeInOut;
var direction = '';
var DIRECTION_LEFT = 'DIRECTION_LEFT';
var DIRECTION_RIGHT = 'DIRECTION_RIGHT';
var currProgress = 0;
var progressFactor = 0.2;
var tl = new TimelineMax({
  paused: true
});

function initVariables() {
  containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
  TweenMax.set(container, {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 'auto'
  });
  containerMaxWidth = container.offsetWidth;
  TweenMax.set(container, {
    clearProps: 'all'
  });
}

function initTimeline() {
  tl.to(inner, totalDuration, {
    x: -containerMaxWidth + containerWidth,
    ease: Power0.easeNone
  });
}

function initListeners() {
  scrollButton.addEventListener('click', doScroll, false);
}

function doScroll() {
  if (direction === DIRECTION_RIGHT) {
    currProgress = currProgress - progressFactor;
  } else {
    currProgress = currProgress + progressFactor;
  }

  if (currProgress >= 1) {
    currProgress = 1;
    direction = DIRECTION_RIGHT;
  } else if (currProgress <= 0) {
    currProgress = 0;
    direction = DIRECTION_LEFT;
  }

  TweenMax.to(tl, duration, {
    progress: currProgress,
    ease: ease
  });
}

//
initVariables();
initTimeline();
initListeners();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed, magnam. Ut sunt nihil quo reprehenderit in voluptas voluptatum at tempore accusamus suscipit ipsam ea atque, unde, itaque quas pariatur architecto.
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  <span id="scroll">Scroll</span>
</p>
```

Basically, here is what is happening here:

- Your `container` element's `width` is stored in a variable called `containerWidth`.
- It then is temporarily set to a `position: absolute` along with its `width: auto`.
- The new width of this `container` element is stored as `containerMaxWidth`.
- The temporarily styles are immediately removed right after using `TweenMax`'s `clearProps: 'all'` setting.
- A `TimelineMax` named `tl` is created which has a defined motion from `x: 0` to the `maximum` position it can scroll to which in this case is `-containerMaxWidth + containerWidth` and this timeline is initially set to `paused`.
- A `direction` variable is indirectly used to update `progress` of our `TimelineMax` instance.
- `currProgress` is directly used to update `progress` of our `TimelineMax` instance.
- This `currProgress` gets calculated based on the `direction` determined above.
- Finally, a tween updates our `tl` instance's `progress` property.

[Here](http://codepen.io/tah_med/pen/QNvBNw?editors=0010) is a codepen result of the above.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to do this another way, but with your suggestions I learned a few tricks that I was able to use in a different project. Accepted this answer.